# Several options for checkout_option in GA Enhanced Ecommerce

Tags: google-analytics

What would be the best way to register several options for a single checkout step with GA Enhanced ecommerce?

As the documentation describes:

```
// Called when user has completed shipping options.
function onShippingComplete(stepNumber, shippingOption) {
  ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {
    'step': stepNumber,
    'option': shippingOption
  });

  ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout', 'Option', {
     hitCallback: function() {
       // Advance to next page.
     }
  });
}
```

The problem is that we collect the shipping and the payment option in one step, and we would like to track both selections. Here is our initial idea:

```
// Called when user has completed shipping and payment options.
function onStepComplete(stepNumber, shippingOption,paymentOption ) {
  ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {
    'step': stepNumber,
    'option': shippingOption
  });

ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {
    'step': stepNumber,
    'option': paymentOption
  });

  ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout', 'Option', {
     hitCallback: function() {
       // Advance to next page.
     }
  });
}
```

Would this work as expected? Could we afterwards segment correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the **checkout_option** to **checkout** - Seems to be the way Google handles the two separate types of events and what data is required for each to work in enhanced ecommerce. Just been facing the same issues myself and have managed to resolve with that fix.

Example based on your code would be:

```
    // Called when user has completed shipping and payment options.
function onStepComplete(stepNumber, shippingOption,paymentOption ) {
  ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': stepNumber,
    'option': shippingOption
  });

ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout', {
    'step': stepNumber,
    'option': paymentOption
  });

  ga('send', 'event', 'checkout', 'option', {
     hitCallback: function() {
       // Advance to next page.
     }
  });
}
```

Comment: Don't track a `checkout` step with the same `stepNumber` twice. See [Andrés Navarro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32131718/1913230) why not

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid options are exclusive and they act as a dimension in the new enhanced checkout funnel reports from GA. If you want to analyse which shipping method works better, then you cannot mix it together with the payment method, both must be different dimensions since the values of a dimension are exclusive.

I would separate shipping and payment in two separate steps each one with their own dimension shipping/payment, even if you have a onestep checkout (quite normal nowadays) you can create as many steps as you want.

Take a look to the [Enhanced Ecommerce Demo Store](https://enhancedecommerce.appspot.com), here they are presenting the payment methods in the step 2 but when the user hits the selector in order to chose Visa/transfer/etc a step 3 is created.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

each step allows only 1 dimension. The solution is to create sub-steps, and when you fire 2 sub-steps remember to send 2 events instead of 1, otherwise the last one will overwrite.

Here it is:

```
                    async.parallel([
                    function shippingOption(callback) {
                        ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {
                            'step': 1,
                            'option': shippingOption
                        });
                        ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout', 'Option', {
                            hitCallback: callback(null, true)
                        });

                    },
                    function paymentOption(callback) {
                        ga('ec:setAction', 'checkout_option', {
                            'step': 2,
                            'option': paymentOption
                        });                                                
                        ga('send', 'event', 'Checkout', 'Option', {
                            hitCallback: callback(null, true)                                
                        })
                    }
                ], function(err, hitCallback){
                   // do something like going to next page
                })
```